# Python: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 34-39: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I've got a data of twitter log and I have to sort the file to show each user's retweeted tweet ranking.

Here's the code.

```
import codecs

with codecs.open('hoge_qdata.tsv', 'r', 'utf-8') as tweets:
    tweet_list = tweets.readlines()

tweet_list.pop(0)
```

---

```
facul={}
for t in tweet_list:
    t = t.split('\t')
    t[-2] = int(t[-2])   
    if t[-2] <= 0:      
        continue        
    if not t[0] in facul:
        facul[t[0]] = []
    facul[t[0]].append(t)

def cmp_retweet(a,b):
    if a[-2] < b[-2]:
        return 1
    if a[-2] > b[-2]:
        return -1
    return 0

for f in sorted(facul.keys()):
    facul[f].sort(cmp=cmp_retweet)
    print ('[%s]' %(f))
    for t in facul[f][:5]:
        print ('%d:%s:%s' % (t[-2], t[2], t[-1].strip())
```

Somehow I got an error saying:

```
print '%d:%s:%s' %(t[-2], t[2], t[-1].strip())
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position
34-39: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Looks like Japanese language letters can't be decoded. How can I fix this? 
I tried to use `sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")` but then I got an error:

```
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'
```

This is how I tried it:

```
import codecs
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

with codecs.open('hoge_qdata.tsv', 'r', 'utf-8') as tweets:
    tweet_list = tweets.readlines()
```

p.s. I am using Python version 2.7.5

Comment: you can try `print ("%d:%s:%s"%(t[-2],t[2].decode(""utf8"),t[-1].decode("utf8")))` (its probably safe to assume that your integer argument does not need to be decoded ...)

Comment: I think sorting is not an issue, so I removed that tag. I added tags for Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

The basic issue, as you have discovered, is that ASCII cannot represent much of unicode.

So you have to make a choice on how to handle it:

- don't display non-ASCII chars
- display non-ASCII chars as some other type of representation

The first choice would like this:

```
for t in facul[f][:5]:
    print ('%d:%s:%s' % (
            t[-2],
            t[2].encode('ascii', errors='ignore'),
            t[-1].encode('ascii', errors='ignore').strip()
            ))
```

While the second choice would replace `ignore` with something like `replace`, `xmlcharrefreplace`, or `backslashreplace`.

Here's [the reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode).

Answer (score 0):

The error message is giving you two clues: first, the problem is in the statement

```
print '%d:%s:%s' %(t[-2], t[2], t[-1].strip())
```

Second, the problem is related to an `encode` operation.  If you don't remember what is meant by "encode", now would be a good time to re-read the [*Unicode HOWTO*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) in the Python 2.7 docs.

It looks like your list `t[]` contains Unicode strings. The `print()` statement is emitting byte strings. The conversion of Unicode strings to byte strings is **encoding**. Because you aren't specifying an encoding, Python is implicitly doing a default encoding. It uses the `ascii` codec, which cannot handle any accented or non-Latin characters.

Try splitting that `print()` statement into two parts. First, insert the unicode `t[]` values into a unicode format string. Note the use of `u''` syntax. Second, encode the unicode string to UTF and print.

```
s = u'%d:%s:%s' %(t[-2], t[2], t[-1].strip())
print s.encode('utf8')
```

(I haven't tested this change to your code. Let me know if it doesn't work.)

I think `sys.setdefaultencoding()` is probably a red herring, but I don't know your environment well.

By the way, the statement, as you write it above, has unbalanced parentheses. Did you drop a right parenthesis when you pasted in the code?

```
print ('%d:%s:%s' %(t[-2], t[2], t[-1].strip())
```